# Are night visions scopes in Fallout 76?

Tags: fallout-76

In Fallout 76, I tend to always scrap weapons, not sell, so I can unlock the mods for the respective weapon. Some weapon types, such as the hunting rifle, do not (or very rarely do) provide any further mods to me when scrapped, since I've already scrapped so many.

However, looking through the list of mods available for my hunting rifles, I don't see any night vision scopes. All flavors (short, medium, long) of standard scope, recon scope, etc., are there, but not one night vision scope.

Do night vision scopes exist in the game? If so, how are they unlockable? Are they simply one type of mod that is not learnable by scrapping, but by plan only?

Answer (score 2):

Are they there, yes.

But only for a few weapons, it seems. They are available in Short, Medium and Long versions for these:

Pipe Weapons

- [Pipe Bolt-Action Pistol](https://fallout76.wiki.fextralife.com/Pipe+Bolt-Action+Short+Night+Vision+Scope)
- [Pipe Pistol](https://fallout76.wiki.fextralife.com/Pipe+Short+Night+Vision+Scope)
- [Pipe Revolver](https://fallout76.wiki.fextralife.com/Pipe+Revolver+Short+Night+Vision+Scope)

And for the [Alien Blaster](https://fallout76.wiki.fextralife.com/Alien+Blaster+Short+Night+Vision+Scope) (only the Short scope).

Source: [Weapon Mods - Fallout 76](https://fallout76.wiki.fextralife.com/Weapon+Mods)

There does not appear to be one for Hunting Rifles.

Comment: I've found that you can put one on a [Combat Shotgun](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hu6jH.png), though why you would ever want a night-vision sniper scope on a shotgun I have no idea.

Comment: Hmm, yeah I wonder if they are just plans out in the world for various versions of the night vision scope. When I was searching it I found some stub pages for one on a plasma rifle and a couple other gun types, but not a whole ton of info, images, or actual hard evidence.  Wonder if people are just reporting them as they find them...

Comment: Might be. I suspect the database files are not local as with previous Fallout versions, which would make it harder to know for certain. I can say though, I've scrapped maybe 200 Hunting Rifles and never seen that scope. Doesn't mean it's not there however :-)

Comment: I do believe I've seen a NV scope plan in a shop for the hunting rifle. I could be wrong though, as this is just from my poorly functioning memory.

Comment: Looking at "Plan: Hunting Rifle Long NV Scope" at a shop right now.

Comment: @Shelby115 Thanks for the info. It's good to know that they can pop up in shops... I do look through the notes section of shops routinely, but no luck yet.

Comment: The Recon scopes also work well at night, and without tinting everything green.

Comment: After a year of game, most rifles now have NV scope plans available, even the more exotic ones, such as Gauss Rifle, Railway rifle, etc.